# how to access the java arraylist type in R

Tags: java, r, arraylist

R call java interface issues.
I knew how to new a java user defined class object as well as call java function in R, some return values can be used directly in R, like integer, string, array, but I have no idea how to access the values of arraylist object.
For example:

```
public class Bond 
{
    public String compName;
    public long mfAmt;


    public Bond() {

    }
}

public class test_arr
{        
        public test_arr()
        { 
        }
        public ArrayList<Bond> getArrListDef()
    {
        ArrayList<Bond> arr = new ArrayList();
        Bond bond = new Bond();
        bond.compName = "app";
        bond.mfAmt = 12;
        arr.add(bond);
        return arr;
    }


        public ArrayList<Bond> getArrList(ArrayList<Bond> arr)
    {
        return arr;
    }
}
```

R call java part:

```
library(rJava)
test_arr = J('pkg.test_arr')
jarr = test_arr$getArrListDef()
```

now, the variable jarr is a Java-Object{}, so how can I print the value of jarr in R...also, how to passing a java arraylist object to another function "public ArrayList getArrList(ArrayList arr)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the `$` convenience operator. It provides an experimental, but simple way of writing code in Java style at the cost of speed. For example to print all elements *mfAmt*

```
for (index in seq(test_arr$size())-1)
  print(test_arr$get(as.integer(index))$mfAmt)
```

Comment: thank you very much,I just did it,but something puzzled me also,becase  the string type of return values is the Chinese characters encoding,thus,when I print this kind of variable,it is  garbled,how can i do?

Comment: Could you please tell me why use operator `$` could be very time consuming,but use `.jcall(...)` not?